# Unrecognized mount option "nobootwait" or missing value on ext4-fs for cloudstack

Tags: fstab, cloudstack

I am launching a VM on a cloudstack derivative.  The `fstab` looks like this

```
/dev/vdb    /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2


         Starting File System Check on /dev/vdb...
[    4.626329] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    4.628322] piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus Host Controller at 0xb100, revision 0
[    4.648258] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    4.656565] alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
[    4.662879] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    4.663720] alg: No test for crc32 (crc32-pclmul)
[    4.836422] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
systemd-fsck[564]: ephemeral0: clean, 11/52428800 files, 3340857/209715200 blocks
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started File System Check on /dev/vdb.
         Mounting /mnt...
[    4.998244] EXT4-fs (vdb): Unrecognized mount option "nobootwait" or missing value
[[1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to mount /mnt.
See 'systemctl status mnt.mount' for details.
```

What would be the correct `fstab` setting for that mount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that option isn't supported. I would just remove it and see what happens, then look at the fstab(5) documentation for the cloudstack derivative.

Comment: More or less what I ended up doing - except used nofail.

Answer (score 2):

I replaced nobootwait with nofail.  It is *not* a great solution but it is the only one presently available to us.